# form trim multiple spaces and take only alphabets

Tags: php, forms

```
<label for="first_name">* First Name </label> 

<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="64" value=<?php echo formatPhone(clean_input($_POST['first_name']); ?>>
```

I have a form where I want to enter a first name. I want the fields to take only alphabets(no numbers). Also when a user enters something like John                   Doe separated by multiple white spaces, I want it to separate the two words only by a single space. I am not sure how this is done in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let pass only ascii names and split the input properly:

```
if (preg_match("~^([A-Z][a-z]+\s*)+$~gm", $value)) {
    // valid

    $array_of_names = preg_split("~\s+~gm", $value);
    // or
    $normalized_name = preg_replace("~\s+~", " ", trim($value));
}
```